# How do I specify an XML struct tag for an element with both attributes and content?

Tags: xml, go

I have to parse something (in a Go program) that looks like:

```
<PARENT>
    <FIRST KEY="something">Value</FIRST>
    <SECOND KEY="something">Value</SECOND>
</PARENT>
```

I've tried:

```
type SomeType struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"PARENT"`
    FirstValue  string   `xml:"FIRST"`
    FirstKey    string   `xml:"FIRST>KEY,attr"`
    SecondValue string   `xml:"SECOND"`
    FirstKey    string   `xml:"SECOND>KEY,attr"`
}
```

but I get this error:

```
xml: FIRST>KEY chain not valid with attr flag
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a type that matches the xml in structure:

```
type T struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"PARENT"`
    First   Value    `xml:"FIRST"`
    Second  Value    `xml:"SECOND"`
}

type Value struct {
    Key   string `xml:"KEY,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/AUoKBxn1Zu5

Answer (score 2):

The answer turns out to be that, for attributes, you don't use a chain of IDs. Rather, you use the ID in a comma separated list, like this:

```
type SomeType struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"PARENT"`
    FirstValue  string   `xml:"FIRST"`
    FirstKey    string   `xml:"FIRST,KEY,attr"`
    SecondValue string   `xml:"SECOND"`
    SecondKey   string   `xml:"SECOND,KEY,attr"`
}
```

My intuition was that everything in the comma separated list was keywords (like `attr` or `omitempty`), so I didn't expect an ID (like `KEY`) to be expressed there, but my intuition was incorrect. More of a discussion on this issue is [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3688).

**Edit:** I spoke too soon. The above doesn't pick up the value of FirstKey or SecondKey.